# How to add pagination in Kibana dashboard visualisation for Horizontal bar/ Piechart

Tags: kibana, dashboard

I am looking for a solution where I want to add the pagination stuff for the horizontal bar/ piechart under kibana dashboard visualization.
We have created the dashboard visualization using Horizontal Bar and applied the aggregation query where we got a set of records which is displayed under the horizontal bar. Let's say if there are a total of 1000 records, the horizontal bar just displays the first 20 records. So to show the remaining 980(1000-20) records part by part is there a way to add pagination kind of stuff in piechart/Horizontal Bar visualization so that when the user clicks on the pagination wizards steps it loads remaining records in horizontal bar/piechart part by part.
Attached a sample horizontal bar for reference where we want to add the pagination.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRA30.jpg)